# CSS3 animation on launch and on hover?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a little problem. I want that the following animation gets fired when the user visits the page AND when he hovers over the element (it's an image). Right now it just fires when visiting the page, but `.animated:hover` gets ignored? Any advice?

```
.animated, .animated:hover {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation: swing 4s;
    -moz-animation: swing 4s;
    -ms-animation: swing 4s;
    -o-animation: swing 4s;
    animation: swing 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center; }
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }  
    30% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg); }   
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg); }    
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); }   
    90% { -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes swing {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); } 
    30% { -moz-transform: rotate(10deg); }  
    40% { -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg); }  
    50% { -moz-transform: rotate(8deg); }   
    60% { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg); }  
    90% { -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); }   
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes swing {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -o-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -o-transform: rotate(-10deg); }   
    30% { -o-transform: rotate(10deg); }    
    40% { -o-transform: rotate(-8deg); }    
    50% { -o-transform: rotate(8deg); } 
    60% { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -o-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -o-transform: rotate(-2deg); }    
    90% { -o-transform: rotate(2deg); } 
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes swing {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }  
    30% { transform: rotate(10deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-8deg); }   
    50% { transform: rotate(8deg); }    
    60% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { transform: rotate(-2deg); }   
    90% { transform: rotate(2deg); }    
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.swing {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    -webkit-animation-name: swing;
    -moz-animation-name: swing;
    -o-animation-name: swing;
    animation-name: swing;
}
```

Comment: Mind making a jsfiddle of this? also why not just create a new keyframe set for the other animation, just copy all the info and apply a new name to it, then make the transform element on "all".

Answer (score 0):

Nice animation, the hover is being cancelled out as its looking for change in the original CSS class, you can fix this by declaring the hover its on animation function.

```
/*PAGE LOAD ANIMATION*/
  .animated{
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation: swing 4s;
    -moz-animation: swing 4s;
    -ms-animation: swing 4s;
    -o-animation: swing 4s;
    animation: swing 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center; }
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }  
    30% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg); }   
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg); }    
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); }   
    90% { -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes swing {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); } 
    30% { -moz-transform: rotate(10deg); }  
    40% { -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg); }  
    50% { -moz-transform: rotate(8deg); }   
    60% { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg); }  
    90% { -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); }   
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes swing {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -o-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -o-transform: rotate(-10deg); }   
    30% { -o-transform: rotate(10deg); }    
    40% { -o-transform: rotate(-8deg); }    
    50% { -o-transform: rotate(8deg); } 
    60% { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -o-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -o-transform: rotate(-2deg); }    
    90% { -o-transform: rotate(2deg); } 
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes swing {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }  
    30% { transform: rotate(10deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-8deg); }   
    50% { transform: rotate(8deg); }    
    60% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { transform: rotate(-2deg); }   
    90% { transform: rotate(2deg); }    
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.swing {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    -webkit-animation-name: swing;
    -moz-animation-name: swing;
    -o-animation-name: swing;
    animation-name: swing;
}
/*HOVER ANIMIATION*/
.animated:hover{
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation: swingHover 4s;
    -moz-animation: swingHover 4s;
    -ms-animation: swingHover 4s;
    -o-animation: swingHover 4s;
    animation: swingHover 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swingHover {
    0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center; }
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }  
    30% { -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg); }   
    50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg); }    
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg); }   
    90% { -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); }    
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes swingHover {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); } 
    30% { -moz-transform: rotate(10deg); }  
    40% { -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg); }  
    50% { -moz-transform: rotate(8deg); }   
    60% { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg); }  
    90% { -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); }   
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes swingHover {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -o-transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { -o-transform: rotate(-10deg); }   
    30% { -o-transform: rotate(10deg); }    
    40% { -o-transform: rotate(-8deg); }    
    50% { -o-transform: rotate(8deg); } 
    60% { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { -o-transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { -o-transform: rotate(-2deg); }    
    90% { -o-transform: rotate(2deg); } 
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes swingHover {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform: rotate(15deg); }
    20% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }  
    30% { transform: rotate(10deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-8deg); }   
    50% { transform: rotate(8deg); }    
    60% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }
    70% { transform: rotate(5deg); }
    80% { transform: rotate(-2deg); }   
    90% { transform: rotate(2deg); }    
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.swingHover {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    -webkit-animation-name: swingHover;
    -moz-animation-name: swingHover;
    -o-animation-name: swingHover;
    animation-name: swingHover;
}
```